# Flutter : Should I need cancel Strem Controller?

Tags: dart, controller, stream

I just transform Firebase auth user status stream to another stream with the stream controller.

```
  final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  StreamController<Oyuncu?> streamController = StreamController<Oyuncu?>();
  late final StreamSubscription _streamSubscription;

  FirebaseAuthService() {
    _streamSubscription = auth.authStateChanges().listen((User? user) {
      if (user != null) {
        streamController.add(Oyuncu(
            ID: user.uid,
            name: user.displayName ?? "Random User Name",
            profilePicture: user.photoURL));
      } else {
        streamController.add(null);
      }
    });
  }
```

Listen is a  Stream Subscription and we need cancel it for avoiding memory leak .But i cant override dispose method. How can I perform cancel correctly?

```
class FirebaseAuthService extends AuthBase {
  final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  StreamController<Oyuncu?> streamController = StreamController<Oyuncu?>();
  late final StreamSubscription _streamSubscription;

  FirebaseAuthService() {
    _streamSubscription = auth.authStateChanges().listen((User? user) {
      if (user != null) {
        streamController.add(Oyuncu(
            ID: user.uid,
            name: user.displayName ?? "Random User Name",
            profilePicture: user.photoURL));
      } else {
        streamController.add(null);
      }
    });
  }


  @override
  anonLogin() async {
    auth.signInAnonymously();
  }

  @override
  Stream<Oyuncu?> userStatus() async* {
    yield* streamController.stream;
  }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You would have to manually cancel it when your FirebaseAuthService is stopped or disposed. In practice, given that you typically start the Auth service when you start your app and never stop it, I wouldn't worry about it.  Disposing a subscription to avoid memory leaks is especially relevant when you do so inside objects that are often created and disposed, such as widgets, and then you can easily cancel in the widget's `dispose` method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I thought the same but I couldn't be sure. https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/cancel_subscriptions.html